# Dynamically apply Tags to AWS CloudFormation Stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

I have been searching for a way to dynamically applied tags to AWS CloudFormation Stack resource. I could not find the right answer. Below is my CloudFormation stack resource.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09' 
Parameters: 
 ami:
  Type: String
 instanceType:
  Type: String
 blockdevice:
  Type: String
Resources: 
 ec2Stack: 
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack 
  Properties: 
   TemplateURL: !Sub "${s3ArtifactPath}/ec2/ec2-base-app.yml"
   Parameters:
     ami: !Ref ami
     instanceType: !Ref instanceType
     blockdevice: !Ref blockdevice
   Tags:
     - Key: sampleKey
       Value: sampleValue
```

I have been trying to find a way where I only pass a list or simply ref a parameter is **Tags** section. Here is what I did

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09' 
Parameters: 
 ami:
   Type: String
 instanceType:
   Type: String
   Default: nbs
   MinLength: 3
   MaxLength: 5
 blockdevice:
   Type: String
 tagsJsonList:
   Type: String
   Default: '[{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}]'
Resources: 
 ec2Stack: 
     Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack 
     Properties: 
       TemplateURL: !Sub "${s3ArtifactPath}/ec2/ec2-base-app.yml"
       Parameters:
         ami: !Ref ami
         instanceType: !Ref instanceType
         blockdevice: !Ref blockdevice
       Tags: !Ref tagsJsonList
```

I was expecting the CloudFormation to formulate the tag list from the variable. The purpose behind this will be that we'll be able to scale in the list and the new tags key-value pairs will be added automatically. This approach did not work.

I also tried the following way

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09' 
Parameters: 
  ami:
    Type: String
  instanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: nbs
    MinLength: 3
    MaxLength: 5
  blockdevice:
    Type: String
Resources: 
  ec2Stack: 
      Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack 
      Properties: 
        TemplateURL: !Sub "${s3ArtifactPath}/ec2/ec2-base-app.yml"
        Parameters:
          ami: !Ref ami
          instanceType: !Ref instanceType
          blockdevice: !Ref blockdevice
        Tags:
          - Key: !Select [0, !Split ["=", !Select [0, !Split [",", !ImportValue someExport] ] ] ]
            Value: !Select [1, !Split ["=", !Select [0, !Split [",", !ImportValue someExport] ] ] ]

# someExport -->  k1=v1,k2=v2,k3=v3
```

1. One problem with this approach is that I can't use Sub intrinsic function to make the someExport variable dynamic.
2. Other problem is that I'll have to write multiple statements for Key, Value statements for applying multiple tags

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this might help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html

Comment: I had to rethink the approach and I got it running using  [AWS::Include](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know you got it working already, but you could try the tag string as:

```
'{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
```

Comment: Yes. Eventually we had to use Custom Resources written in Java and integrated those in our CloudFormation. Thanks for your response.